# iPhone: Is it necessary to upload the app to itunes to test In App Purchase?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase, ios4

Is it necessary to upload the app to itunes to test In App Purchase?

Comment: @Silverback: Think about it: it that were true, then everyone would need to implement the In App code blindly, upload their app, wait for it to get approved, then see whether it works or not, then try to debug it (without the possibility of having debug symbols) while their users are complaining. Would be pretty bad, wouldn't it ? :-)

Comment: You do but it doesn't need to be fully completed. Just reject the binary once you upload it.

Comment: @DarkDust: Thanks for the input. I just asked whether we need to upload the binary. I didnt ask whether it should be approved before we can test it. Hope you get it. I found a similar comment to what @Jamie has said above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you just have to set up your In-App Purchases in iTunes Connect and create a test user, then you can test in the sandbox. Read [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH103-SW1).

Edit: there's also an In-App Purchase session in the list of [WWDC 2011 session videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/). You might learn something from that too.

Comment: Yes you do. If you are downloading product data etc. you need an app to link your in app purchase to.

Comment: What do you mean? You can create an app in iTunes Connect without actually uploading the app.

Comment: I just went through this myself. Have you successfully retrieved a  valid product ID from the store without uploading any binary?

Comment: Are you talking about SKProductsRequest?

Comment: Yes. I was unable to retrieve mine until I had a binary online.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is necessary. Prior to submitting a binary I was getting a message through iTunes connect saying a binary must be submitted with the In-app purchase.

It seems perverse, but you have to do the following:

1. Create your app in iTunes (or your new version)
2. Add your In-App purchase in iTunes
3. Associate your In-App purchase with the new version of your app (click on the version, scroll down to in-app purchases, click edit, add the purchase(s))
4. Then  build your app for distribution and upload it to the iTunes store.
5. Once uploaded, click on the binary and click Reject to change the status to Developer Rejected. This means Apple won't approve it, however the In-App purchase will still be Waiting For Review.

Also make sure your provisioning profile doesn't include the wildcard '*' character.

There's a great article here which is a little out of date but still very helpful: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

It's a clunky process I don't think Apple though through too well in advance...